# Conditional branching in Google Forms (checkbox)

Tags: google-forms

I'm creating a google form and I've stumbled across this issue: I have a checkbox with options, say: A, B and C; so that it's possible for a respondent to choose more than 1 answer. And I have the SAME set of questions to ask about each option, that is if a respondent chooses "A" option only, they should see questions only about "A", and if they choose "A" and "C", they should be given a set of questions about "A" and then (the same set of questions) about "C".
As I understand this, showing particular sheets for each option would work here great, but it's not possible for a checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Google Forms doesn't have the workflow controls that you are looking for.

## Explanation

Google Forms has a way to set the next question page to be shown, but this only works for dropdown and multiple choice (radio button) questions.

## See also

["Go to section based on answer" checkbox](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/docs/%22Go$20to$20section$20based$20on$20answer%22$20checkbox)
[Show questions based on answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)